# Call SharePoint webservice with NTLM and custom credentials

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm working with a SharePoint webservice called : copy.asmx

Here is my web.config used to call this service

```
<binding name="CopySoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="655360" maxReceivedMessageSize="655360"
          textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
          messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
```

I need to send custom credentials to this service using something like that :

```
CopySoapClient client = new CopySoapClient();
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential() { UserName = "foooooooo", Password = "foofoo", Domain = "domain" };

    FieldInformation myFieldInfo = new FieldInformation();
    FieldInformation[] myFieldInfoArray = { myFieldInfo };
    byte[] myByteArray;
    client.GetItem(XmlParser.GetUriFromConfiguration("LocalisationUri"), out myFieldInfoArray, out myByteArray);
```

Is it possible to have a sample who works to call a NTLM sharepoint webservice with custom credentials ?

Comment: what do you mean by NTLM custom credentials ?  hard wired used name and password ?,  impersonation ?

Comment: using name and password of an ad account this good rights on the sharepoint list

Comment: It's a webservice the easiset thing to do, as it's a AD account, is set up the IIS app to run under the AD account, so it runs always in the account context,thinks that's the App pool, and your actual site (not the pool) can be set to either integrated Auth or anonymous

Comment: security policy forbids me to do this, it would be too easy !